# wercker how to show tests informations in the status badge

Tags: wercker

The only information I can show in my github repo is the build status

[image]

Is there a possible way to show additional information, like test coverage, skipped tests ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. You can add the suggestion [here](https://wercker.uservoice.com/forums/181077-general)